# Bit twiddling with GMP

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, gmp

I have a variable of type `mpz_class`. In its binary form, I would like to get its last `n` digits. I would normally achieve this by using a bit mask and shifting `(1 << n)-1` but GMP doesn't seem to have a simple left shift operator. An alternative approach might involve `get_str(2)` to get the string version of the binary representation, but for large numbers I would imagine this would be wasteful.

**What's the best way to get the last n digits from a variable of type `mpz_class`?**

I have found `mpn_lshift()` in https://gmplib.org/manual/Low_002dlevel-Functions.html but it seems overly complex for a simple task. It would be useful if someone could provide me with a simple example of how it could be used with `mpz_class`.

I have tried this code and it doesn't compile because of `<<`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gmpxx.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    mpz_class a(5);
    cout << "a: " << a << endl;
    mpz_class b = (mpz_class(1) << a);
    cout << "b: " << b << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `mpz_class(1)<<a.get_ui()`. Since it doesn't make sense to shift by a number that does not fit in `unsigned long` (the result wouldn't fit in memory), `operator<<` takes that as second argument, not `mpz_class`.

Comment: @MarcGlisse to remove the last n digits from `mpz_class` would it be `>>` or `>>>`?

Comment: There is no such thing as >>> in C++.

Comment: In this context `operator<<` is defined in the GMP library, right? I can't find any documentation on it. Got a link?

Comment: In "C++ Interface General": "The standard operators [...] are overloaded to allow arithmetic with these classes." I don't think it goes into more details than that.

Comment: Ok. I found some strange behaviour. If `mpz_class x(33); mpz_class y = 1 << x;` this gives the wrong result (with no errors) becasue 1 needs to be `mpz_class(1)`. I wouldn't normally expect this, just because an operand can't handle the value, the variable being assigned to still can.

Comment: You must be using some strange compiler, gcc and clang both reject that code.

Comment: The example I gave was too simple. This produces unexpected results on g++ `unsigned long y = 50;mpz_class x = (1 << y);cout << x << endl;`. The correct result is `‭1,125,899,906,842,624‬` but `262144` is displayed. And there's no error message at run or compile time.

Comment: Did I do something to cause UB? I'm not sure if this is related to GMP or not.

Comment: You need to learn how the language works! the compiler sees 1<<y, 1 has type int, it computes the shift in type int, that overflows. GMP hasn't been involved at all at this point. Only later you try to construct some x based on this wrong value.

Comment: I thought it wouldn't matter since it's an intermediate value and then the result is stored in mpz.